# Search for documents with the same value in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, self-join

I have a schema that looks something like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "entity": {
      "properties": {
      "a": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "b": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to find all the values of b which have a value of a which is shared by 2 or more entities:

Querying against:

```
[{"a": "a1", "b": "b1"}, 
 {"a": "a1", "b": "b2"}, 
 {"a": "a2", "b": "b3"}]
```

Should return `b1` and `b2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `terms` aggregation on the `a` field with a `min_doc_count` of 2 and then add a `top_hits` sub-aggregation to find the matching `b` fields:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "dups": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "a",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "b_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": "b"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```