# Get a list of all duplicate documents in Elastic Search index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Imagine I have documents like this:

```
{
  "customerId" : "some-id",
  ...
}
```

How can I retrieve a list of all documents that have a non-unique value in the `customerId` field?

So, for this collection:

```
{ "customerId" : "0" },
{ "customerId" : "0" },
{ "customerId" : "1" },
{ "customerId" : "2" },
{ "customerId" : "3" },
{ "customerId" : "3" },
{ "customerId" : "4" },
```

I would need to get this collection as result:

```
{ "customerId" : "0" },
{ "customerId" : "3" },
```

I need this in 1 query that is executable the "`Dev Tools`" tab in [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana), not as a combination or by using multiple queries in a specific SDK (e.g. Elastic Search Java API).

This is the query that I tried, but it turns out that the results are not correct:

```
POST /_xpack/sql?format=txt
{
  "query": "SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(customerId) document_count, documentId count FROM "my-index" GROUP BY customerId) WHERE document_count > 1"
}
```

This query is also in SQL, which is not optimal when interacting with Elastic Search. It would be nice to have a query written in Query DSL.

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51669565/4604579 (hint: `terms` aggregation with `min_doc_count: 2`

Comment: Thank you! It says on the documentation that [`terms` queries are not always accurate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts). Are there any other methods that will always return an accurate result?

Comment: You should first try to see if it works for you, I think it'll get you a long way before hitting road blocks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for documents with the same value in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669448/search-for-documents-with-the-same-value-in-elasticsearch)